# Setup issues using the hw watchdog with systemd

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a post using the hardware watchdog on a Raspberry Pi running Jessie. I have created a post on the raspberry Pi forum, but up until now no replies with help.

Rather than repeating everything here, this is the link with my setup woes.
[Raspi Forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?uid=52264&f=29&t=147501&start=0)

The setup procedure is complicated, awkward, poorly documented and confusing. I would like to solicit help to get it right, or pointers to where I should direct a bug report. (watchdog itself works, so does systemd, where do I go for these integration issues?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Paulv's link and post explains how to do this - check it out for explanations and more info](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=147501).

If you just want the setup do this:

1. Install the watchdog package

`sudo apt-get install watchdog`

2. Add a line to the watchdog service file

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service`

insert after [install]

```
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Enable on boot

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

```
sudo systemctl enable watchdog
```

4. Reboot and check status

`sudo systemctl status watchdog`

Answer (score 0):

I'd repeat what Paulv said, and I think you will also need to enable the Broadcom watchdog module (`bcm2835_wdt`) in modules:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835_wdt

echo "bcm2835_wdt" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```